# NHibernate - Is there a way to map a formula that uses sql function and returns Table?!

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, formula

I have a sql function that returns table and I need to map it to a collection i'm trying with formula but as far as i can tell formula is good only to single returned value (right?!?)

is there a way to use formula and map it to a DataTable or some other collection

```
<propery name="Prop" type="DataTable" formula="select function(...)"/>
```

if not what are my other options?!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate

For return value you can use DTO or Persistence class